# How to create an undefined value in a JSON Object in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to build a JSON object which is built in Rails.

My object is:

```
person = {name: "david", age: 25, address: nil}
```

but the address appears as null and not undefined

person.to_json ======>

```
{name: "david", 
 age: 25, 
 address: null  <---- I want this to be undefined
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your can use Ruby method `compact` to remove nil properties before converting to json:

```
person = {name: "david", age: 25, address: nil}
person.compact.to_json
```

which would return:

```
{
  name: "david", 
  age: 25 
}
```

that way `person.address`will be undefined

Comment: This answers the question, but @AdrianE, you should make your javascript treat null and undefined the same, otherwise you will create a fragile communication system between your rails and javascript code.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 6):

`undefined` is not valid JSON, even though it is valid in javascript.

> A JSON value can be an object, array, number, string, true, false, or
>   null.

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf

Comment: IMHO `undefined` is one the stupidest misstakes in the design of the Javascript language. JSON and Ruby got it right by just using one type to represent nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jbuilder, you can use `json.ignore_nil!` at the start of your view and it will not generate any json with a nil value. Even better, you can set it globally in an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/jbuilder.rb
Jbuilder.ignore_nil true
```

Just remember to restart the rails server after adding the initializer